Is stoichiometry not applicable at equilibrium?
While studying equilibrium, I came across this question-
CO(g) + 2H₂(g) ⇌ CH₃OH(g)
Hydrogen gas is introduced into a 5-L flask at 327°C, containing 0.2 mol of CO(g) and a catalyst, until the pressure is 4.92 atm. At equilibrium, 0.1 mol of CH₃OH(g) is formed. If the value of Kp = β/(4.92)^2. What is the value of β?
(Kp is equilibrium constant in terms of partial pressure. Kc is that, in terms of concentration.)
Here's what I thought for this question.
We need Kp, but what we have are moles, so we use Kc and its relation with Kp to find β.
I started solving for Kc but realised that initial moles of H2 are not given. So I used stoichiometry, and applied the following-
if 1 mole of CO reacts with 2 moles of H2, then 0.2 moles of CO will react 0.4 moles of H2.
However, this step is wrong, but I don't clearly see why.
I proceeded further as -




CO
H2
CH30H




t =0
0.2 moles
0.4
0


t = t.eq
0.2-x
0.4-2x
x



but, x = 0.1 (given)




CO
H2
CH30H




t = t.eq
0.1
0.2
0.1



My answer, at the end, was wrong. Why is stoichiometry not applicable here? Is it because there might be a grater amount of H2 present, than what is reacting?
For reference, the answer is 25/9.

Four formatting guides for chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics // Detailed // Upright vs Italics // Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// Not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

It is always good to describe the problem/task primarily with symbolic algebraic expressions . And it is good to keep it that way until all is ready to just plug-in literal numbers with explicit units. It helps in focusing on principles, mistakes are easier to spot, orientation is improved, Q/A is reusable and has bigger  permanent value.

It is not given, unless verified, that both gases are in stoichiometric ratio.

Let:
A $\to$ $\ce{CO(g)}$
B $\to$ $\ce{H2(g)}$
C $\to$ $\ce{CH3OH(g)}$
The change in stoichiometric amounts for this particular reaction is:
$\Delta n=1-1-2\implies \boxed{\Delta n=-2}$
Since the reaction is carried in a sealed vessel and there is no temperature dependance mentioned with respect to the equilibrium constants, then we can assume the process is both isochoric and isothermal, and the following relationship remains constant even after equilibrium is reached:
$$\frac{RT}{V}=\frac{RT_o}{V_o}=\frac{\left(\pu{0.08206\frac{L\cdot atm}{K\cdot mol}}\right)\left(\pu{600K}\right)}{\pu{5L}}\implies \boxed{\frac{RT}{V}= \pu{9.85\frac{atm}{mol}}}$$
Using the given initial partial pressure of B and the previous result, we can calculate the initial amount of B:
$$n_\mathrm{{B_O}}=\frac{P_\mathrm{{B_O}}V}{RT}=\frac{\pu{4.92atm}}{\pu{9.85\frac{atm}{mol}}}\implies \boxed{n_\mathrm{{B_O}}=\pu{0.50mol}}$$
Now we can use the given value of $x=\pu{0.10mol}$ to calculate the equilibrium amounts of all species:
$$n_\mathrm{A}=n_\mathrm{{A_O}}-x=\left(0.20-0.10\right)\pu{mol}\implies \boxed{n_\mathrm{A}=\pu{0.10mol}}$$
$$n_\mathrm{B}=n_\mathrm{{B_O}}-2x=\left(0.50-0.20\right)\pu{mol}\implies \boxed{n_\mathrm{B}=\pu{0.30mol}}$$
$$n_\mathrm{C}=x\implies \boxed{n_\mathrm{C}=\pu{0.10mol}}$$
Now we can calculate the equilibrium constant in terms of amounts:
$$K_n=\frac{n_\mathrm{C}}{n_\mathrm{A}\;n_\mathrm{B}^2}=\frac{0.1}{(0.1)(0.3)^2}\implies \boxed{K_n=11.11}$$
Finally, we can use the relationship between $K_P$ and $K_n$, as well as the expression given for $K_P$ to solve for $\beta$:
$$K_P=K_n\left(\frac{RT}{V}\right)^{\Delta n}=\frac{\beta}{4.92^2}$$
Solving for $\beta$:
$$\beta=4.92^2K_n\left(\frac{RT}{V}\right)^{\Delta n}$$
Plugging in all the previously calculated values:
$$\beta=(4.92)^2(11.11)\left(9.85\right)^{-2}\implies \boxed{\pmb{\beta=2.77\approx\frac{25}{9}}}$$
$\pmb{Final \;comments:}$
As Poutnik stated, unless explicitly stated in the problem statement or not enough data is given, never assume initial amounts are in a stoichiometric ratio. In this particular case, the given partial pressure of hydrogen gas can be used to calculate its initial amount using the ideal gas law.
